# Search and replace line matching first instance of keyword starting from point of another keyword search

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file which is modified via a shell script.

I need to do the following:

1. Take input from user for new text.
2. Search for keyword #1 in the file.
3. Starting from 2. , search forward for keyword #2.
4. Replace the line (containing keyword #2) with user supplied input.

For example, my file has the following text:

```
(some text)  
(some text)  
(text1_to_search)  
(some text)  
(text2_to_search) <- **This needs to be replaced only**  
(text2_to_search)    
(some text)
```

I just need to replace that specific line and leave the rest of the file content untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
awk '/text1_to_search/,/text2_to_search/ && !found{
if($0 ~ /text1_to_search/){found=0};
if($0 ~ /text2_to_search/){print "replacement";found=1;next}};
{print}'
```

For two non-overlapping search/replaces

```
awk '/text1_to_search/,/text2_to_search/ && !found{if($0 ~ /text1_to_search/){found=0};if($0 ~ /text2_to_search/){print "replacement";found=1;next}};
/Search_String2/,/Search_String3/ && !found2{if($0 ~ /SearchString2/){found2=0};if($0 ~ /Search_String3/){print "replacement2";found2=1;next}};
{print}'
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks.

However, am doing 2 such searches for different strings in the same file. Can i club them so that the new file creation happens only once?

Comment: @chingupt, are the search ranges in your data non-overlapping?

Comment: awk '$0 ~ /\"Search_string\"/ {print; getline; print replacement1; next} {print} ' replacement1="sometext" origFile > tmpfile1
awk '/search_string2/,/Search_String3/ {if ($0 ~ /Search_String3/){print replacement2; next}}; {print}' replacement2="sometext" tmpfile1 > tmpfile2
mv tmpfile2 origFile

Comment: Hi @1_CR
This is not working. From the point it finds the first search string, it writes 2-3 lines on the output.

Comment: @chingupt, apologies, see the new version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32574/discussion-between-chingupt-and-1-cr)

Comment: can you please help? stuck with trying to pass user defined parameters as replacements.

Comment: @chingupt, `var1=text1_to_search`, `var2=text2_to_search`, `awk '/'$var1'/,/'$var2'/......'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'done{print;next}found&&/text2/{while(getline<"replacement")print;done=1;next}/text1/{found=1}1'
```

That assumes you have a file called "replacement" with the replacement.
The following two replace via regex:

```
sed '/text1/,/text2/s/text2/foo/' test.in
```

If they are on the same line, this will replace that one and the next. The following will only alter the later one.

```
awk 'found&&!done&&/text2/{done=sub(/text2/,"foo")}/text1/{found=1}1' test.in
```